# Parsing serial data continuously - is there a better approach?

Tags: c, string, embedded, uart

I'm writing an application for usart driver for receiving serial data and making use of it. for that, I have a loop that continually checks for the input, and once "enter" is hit, the ISR (not shown) gets exited and we are back in `main`. Then we parse the newly entered data from `arr` that contains a bunch of different inputs.

if you are constantly receiving input from the user, are creating temporary variables as I did for storing the parsed strings too much of an overkill? Could it be done in a better way?

```c
char arr[30], temp[30], parsedData[30];
char *ptr = arr; // increments for each byte received
char *prevPtr = arr;
Usart usart;

void receive_data(Usart *usart) {
   *usart = data_register;
   usart++;
}

int main() {
    usart.rx_buffer = arr;
    // other init...

    while (true) {
      receive_data(&usart); // populates `arr`
      strncpy(temp, arr, (ptr-prevPtr));   // copy the newly entered bytes into `temp`

      // now parse until '\r'
      const *end = ststr(temp, "\r");
      strncpy(parsedData, temp, (end-temp));  
      // do whatever with parsedData now...
    }
}

/* example of how `arr` would look like as we receive inputs
first attempt: `acceleration\r` // parse acceleration
second attempt: `acceleration\rtemperature\r` // parse temperature
*/
...
```

Comment: What causes `receive_data` to return?  What happens to received serial data when `receive_data()` is *not* active?

Comment: this isn't a *complete* code, but enough to demonstrate the issue I think. The point I'm getting at the logic behind parsing the data

Comment: Copying data from an active receive buffer to a working area so you can do stuff with it seems reasonable to me, especially if this will allow you to reset the receive buffer for the next round so data can clock in while you're working with the copy.  Do you have reason to believe that this is going to cause you problems?

Comment: No, just the way i'm parsing the user input mainly is what I'm concerned with (design-wise)

Comment: Consider that code may be able to to 100s to 1000s instructions per byte arrival - I doubt serial handling is a big issue.

Comment: in what sense do you mean?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica - That depends on which architecture the code is running on.

Comment: but I'm trying to understand the reference to 100-1000s instructions per byte arrival

Comment: Serial  data arrives at perhaps 9600-115200 baud.  Lets say 57600 baud or 5760 data bytes per second.  Processor runs at maybe 10 to 100 MHz, lets say 20 M instructions / second. That is 3500 instructions per byte.  An embedded processor has lots of CPU power to do things so it would be mostly idling with OP's code regardless of how efficient it may be.

Comment: Yeah no that makes sense. Back to the circular buffer, I'm still trying to get if I really need it considering I have two buffers each for TX and RX.

Answer (score 0):

> Could it be done in a better way?

"once "enter" is hit, the ISR (not shown) gets exited and we are back in main" is most unusual.

I am unfamiliar with `Usart` to offer better authoritatively.

A more common paradigm it to store incoming data in a circular queue and increment a count  when `'\n'` arrives and a count of bytes in the queue.

The reader than decrements as it takes them out.

Care is needed to insure the ISR is not activate when the other code accesses these variables and visa-versa.

A key weakness to OP's approach is the assumption that the main code will get everything done after the `'\n'` arrives yet before the next message starts.  I would not count on that.

---

IMO, code is broken is various ways:

**No null character**

`ststr(temp, "\r");` expects `temp` to contain a `'\0'` after the last character put in it.  Instead is has left-overs from before and is prone to buffer overflow.

Far better to treat incoming data as an array bytes than a C *string*.

**Missing code?**

The below says "increments for each byte received" yet there is no code that indicates that.

**Missing code?**

Nothing indicates `usart` stops filling `arr` at 30 bytes.

Comment: Well, I disable the control bits once either the rx length hits 0 or enter is pressed by the user. you don't want to keep reading bits till rx length is 0. If I want something from the device, I'd enter what I want and that's it. I don't have to wait till the entire buffer is full for it to give me something.

doesn't `strstr` look for the string that you provide in the second parameter and not care much about `\0` though I agree the string doesn't have a null terminator but it could've been avoided by first initializing to 0 so we don't have to worry about uninitialized bytes

Comment: @xyf  1)Using `ststr(temp, "\r");` with a `temp` that certainly contain a `'\r'` is _likely_ OK, yet still UB.   2) By _array of bytes_, simply a sequence of `unsigned char`/bytes with an auxiliary  length.  3) Consider that real serial communication is prone to unexpected errors and robust codes does not rely on a `'\n'` to occur within 30 received bytes.

Comment: @xyf "but it could've been avoided by first initializing to 0 so we don't have to worry about uninitialized bytes " is only good for the first message.  The next message inherits the previous messages values for the unused bytes on the new message.

Comment: 1) It's UB because...the buffer isn't initialized to 0, yeah? 2) I do have array of bytes `char`? not sure what you're referring to. 3) well if you don't expect `\n` to occur in 30 received bytes so be it. It comes down to the application; in mines, I expect the user to input the command followed by an enter. I couldn't think of any other way around it... 4) well so we `memset` the buffer to 0 prior to reading again. that's what I tried: https://cplayground.com/?p=lemur-crocodile-louse

Comment: @xyf Don't use string functions with something that is not a _string_.  All strings, by definition in C, have a _null character_ termination.

Comment: "I expect the user to input the command followed by an enter. " --> does not consider the failures that occur due to serial transmission - it is not a robust as one hopes.

Comment: can you elaborate on your first comment regarding not using string functions with something that isn’t a string? Not sure what you’re referring to. And I’m aware of the fact that C strings have null terminator.

Comment: 2) that goes for any other bit. Isn’t this what parity checks are for?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212921/discussion-between-chux-reinstate-monica-and-xyf).